# Is there any way to use Roboguice and ActionbarSherlock in one project?

Tags: android, android-library, actionbarsherlock

I'd like to use the libraries mentioned in the title in one project.

However, both need my Activities to extend from a special Activity class: in the case of Roboguice it's RoboAcitivity, and it's FragmentActivity for ActionbarSherlock.

ActionbarSherlock extends the compatibility library, which is nice, because I also need to use fragments, and the project level s < API level 11.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this? Since Java does not support multiple inheritance (which is a good thing usually), I tried to make the FragmentActivity in the ActionbarSherlock project to extend RoboActivity instead of the standard Activity. But I can't get it to compile this way.

Part of the console output is:

```
[2011-10-15 17:46:31 - RetainFragmentTest2] /Users/scythe/JavaLibs/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-a4855d0/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:170: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:logo'.
[2011-10-15 17:46:31 - RetainFragmentTest2] /Users/scythe/JavaLibs/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-a4855d0/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:171: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:navigationMode'.
[2011-10-15 17:46:31 - RetainFragmentTest2] /Users/scythe/JavaLibs/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-a4855d0/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:174: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:progressBarPadding'.
[2011-10-15 17:46:31 - RetainFragmentTest2] /Users/scythe/JavaLibs/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-a4855d0/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:176: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:subtitle'.
[2011-10-15 17:46:31 - RetainFragmentTest2] /Users/scythe/JavaLibs/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-a4855d0/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:177: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:subtitleTextStyle'.
[2011-10-15 17:46:31 - RetainFragmentTest2] /Users/scythe/JavaLibs/JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-a4855d0/library/res/values-v11/abs__styles.xml:173: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:titleTextStyle'.
```

Comment: You are being too greedy I think :P
But I feel ur problem is because of abs_styles not having the attributes mentioned

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but [this is how I finally got ActionBarSherlock and RoboGuice working in my little app](http://flexamusements.blogspot.com/2011/11/actionbarsherlock-and-roboguice-can-be.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this!

Answer (score 6):

Besides the issues with the compatibility library, you might also struggle with how to extend your activity both from `RoboActivity`and `SherlockActivity` - in Java, you don't have mulitple inheritance :-)

The way you solve this is by hand-crafting your own `RoboSherlockActivity` or use 
[Roberto Tyley's library](https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock).

See [example](https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rtyley/android/sherlock/roboguice/activity/RoboSherlockActivity.java).

Answer (score 3):

I would just like to add that by 'simply' adding roboguice-sherlock to your maven pom it magicly works.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.rtyley</groupId>
        <artifactId>roboguice-sherlock</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example just got released on github. It uses a whole bunch of other good tools in additon. Check out https://github.com/github/gauges-android

Answer (score 0):

Another example of a working example and utility can be found here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.rtyley%7Croboguice-sherlock%7C1.3%7Cjar

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [RoboGuice 3](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/WhatsNew30), the [roboguice-sherlock](https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock) framework is [included in the RoboGuice distribution](https://plus.google.com/+MichaelBurton1/posts/CCk5bpNuGyV).
The naming scheme for the class is still the [same](https://github.com/rtyley/roboguice-sherlock/blob/roboguice-sherlock-1.5/README.markdown)

> All classes in this project have the same name as the RoboGuice ones, with 'Sherlock' inserted after the 'Robo', ie Robo**Sherlock**ListFragment

except that the classes now reside in the [`roboguice.activity`](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/tree/roboguice-aggregator-3.0/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity) package.
See [`RoboSherlockActivity`](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/roboguice-aggregator-3.0/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity/RoboSherlockActivity.java) for example.